# Preferred way to approach expired records delition in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, triggers, backend, expirationhandler

There are 3 tables in the database -- `Students`, `Courses`, `Professors`.
Each student has `activation_deadline` column, which is set to `NULL` upon activation. I need some mechanism that will periodically delete students who's `activation_deadline` is overdue (and prevent already '*expired*' students from being activated).

At the moment I do it via three separate triggers (as [there are no database or server level triggers in SQLite](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/280870)) for `Students` table.

One for `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Unactivated_Students_Update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Students
    WHERE (activation_deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'));
END;
```

One for `INSERT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Unactivated_Students_Insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON Students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Students
    WHERE (activation_deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'));
END;
```

And one for `DELETE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Unactivated_Students_Delete
AFTER DELETE
ON Students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Students
    WHERE (activation_deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'));
END;
```

Another approach would be to add some code to the backend, which will check and remove expired records before any other query to database is executed (though, it will increase amount of database calls, and this is not good).

Which (keeping '*expired*' records removing logic in **database trigger or backend**) approach in this circumstances is preferred and why? What are the pitfalls and advantages of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is a [serverless](https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html) [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_management_system) and you can't define/schedule tasks or jobs.

Your requirement should be taken care of at the application level, where you can define a daily or weekly job to delete *expired* students.

This involves the execution of only 1 very simple and fast `DELETE` statement, once per day/week:

```
DELETE FROM Students WHERE activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now');
```

Note that the condition `activation_deadline IS NOT NULL` is covered by `activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now')`, so it is not needed.

Any solution involving multiple triggers is out of the question, because it would add unnecessary overhead to any simple `INSERT`/`DELETE`/`UPDATE` operation on the table.

Comment: Nice point concerning redundancy of `activation_deadline IS NOT NULL`. What would you say about using a single trigger (just to prevent activation of already expired students) something like: `CREATE TRIGGER Prevent_Expired_Student_Activation BEFORE UPDATE OF activation_deadline ON Students FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM Students WHERE activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'); END;` in combination with a periodical backend job?

Comment: It could work. But you may consider dealing with such a requirement with a CONSTRAINT if you add a new column like `activated_at`. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f88bd6fc9e68de27d6179458674aa1dc

Comment: Thanks for pointing to another ([constraint](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#check_constraints)-based) solution.